# ionic3 set timeout for ion-input on searching address

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, settimeout

When user enters the address on ion-input, I want to setTimeout for 500ms instead of keep calling http request for each of the keyup. What it is doing now is keep on calling http request for 15 times if I keypress 15 times on keyboard. And everytime it searches new address, I want to clear everything in the array but now it is not being cleared. Right now i Ctrl+V to paste the address, so there will be two keypress and searchAddress() will be called twice and the first time of addressSearchRslts array is not being cleared as you can see from the image below:

[image]

This is the console output when searchAddress() is being called:

[image]

> What I want is '1/84 solomon rd' should only call searchAddress() **ONCE**

I know this is being called twice because of keypress behaviour. Is there any way to achieve searchAddress() being called just once by using setTimeout()

my .ts

```
@ViewChild('addressInput') addressInput;

addressSearchRslts = [];
searchAddress:string;

searchAddress(event: any){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.addressInput.setFocus();
    }, 500);
    this.addressSearchRslts.length=0;
    if(this.searchAddress.length<1){
      return;
    }
    this._service.searchAddress(this.searchAddress).subscribe(
      success=>{
        let searchRslts=success.addresses.slice(0, 100);
        searchRslts.forEach( (result )=>{
          let address = result;
          let addressInfo = address.house_number+' '+address.street+', '+address.district+' '+address.state+' '+address.postal_code+' '+address.country;
          this.addressSearchRslts.push( {data:address, title:addressInfo});
        });
      },err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('search address finish')
    );
}

selectAddress(data){
    this.address.setValue(data.house_number+' '+data.street);
    this.city.setValue(data.district);
    this.state.setValue(data.state);
    this.postcode.setValue(data.postal_code);
    this.addressSearchRslts.length=0;
}
```

my html

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Address</ion-label>
      <ion-input #addressInput id="addressField" type="text" formControlName="address" [(ngModel)]="searchAddress" (keyup)="searchAddress($event)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="addressSearchRslts.length>0">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let addressSearchRslt of addressSearchRslts" (click)="selectAddress(addressSearchRslt.data)">
        <p ion-text text-wrap>{{addressSearchRslt.title}}</p> 
      </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a debounce on the ion-input, over here is a nice example of a directive you can implement to achieve this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-add-debounce-on-ion-input-in-ionic/115693/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your service call to settimeout and have a boolean value to check if service has already been called, with this approach your service should be called every 500 ms irrespective of the number of keys you pressed

```
  @ViewChild('addressInput') addressInput;

  addressSearchRslts = [];
  searchAddress: string;
  searchCalled = false;

  searchAddress(event: any) {
    if (!this.searchCalled) {
      this.searchCalled = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addressInput.setFocus();
        this.addressSearchRslts.length = 0;
        if (this.searchAddress.length < 1) {
          return;
        }
        this._service.searchAddress(this.searchAddress).subscribe(
          success => {
            let searchRslts = success.addresses.slice(0, 100);
            searchRslts.forEach((result) => {
              let address = result;
              let addressInfo = address.house_number + ' ' + address.street + ', ' + address.district + ' ' + address.state + ' ' + address.postal_code + ' ' + address.country;
              this.addressSearchRslts.push({ data: address, title: addressInfo });
            });
          }, err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('search address finish')
        );
        this.searchCalled = false;
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  selectAddress(data) {
    this.address.setValue(data.house_number + ' ' + data.street);
    this.city.setValue(data.district);
    this.state.setValue(data.state);
    this.postcode.setValue(data.postal_code);
    this.addressSearchRslts.length = 0;
  }
```